# Looking for some steganography guidance

Tags: cryptography, python, steganography, ctf

I am currently trying to figure out a steganography challenge. I was given 3 images, a secret.txt file and a "binary" file. There are no instructions as this was part of another challenge. I am looking for someone to point me in the right direction. I just cant seem to make anything out of it lol. [Here is a link to the files](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByxdLVl9aUTdME95a0xKTDZNT28/view?usp=sharing).

Not looking for anyone to solve this for me, just offer some guidance on tools to use and what direction to go. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For JPG images it is possible to use a tool called Stegdetect to identify images which are suspicious to bare the steganographic content and identify a tool used to hide the message. It can even try to decode or bruteforce some of the algorithms. Original site of the tool disappeared from internet, but you can still download the tool from some trustworthy archives like Debian - https://archive.debian.net/etch/utils/stegdetect
Here is guide how to install on Kali linux - http://rfc.red/installing-stegdetect-in-kali-linux/
http://freecode.com/projects/stegdetect/

Some more tools:

- steghide - http://steghide.sourceforge.net/
- stegui - GUI for steghide - http://stegui.sourceforge.net/steghide.html
- JPHide - http://linux01.gwdg.de/~alatham/stego.html
- Outguess - stego tool from the same author as stegdetect

  - https://archive.debian.net/squeeze/outguess
  - http://web.archive.org/web/20150508205355/http://www.outguess.org/download.php
- OutguessRebirth - http://www.outguess-rebirth.com/
- OpenStego - https://sourceforge.net/projects/openstego/
- Camouflage - http://camouflage.unfiction.com/
- and probably many more:
  https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=stegano

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the jpeg images have been encoded with a stenography tool (such as steghide). As you're probably aware, stegonography is the process of embedding messages or other data within an image. Often it is difficult to see the difference between the original and the altered jpgs with the naked eye.

Tools like stegdetect will identify if the the 3 jpegs are suspected of containing hidden info. Often the tool used to perform the stenography will allow the stenographer to protect the resulting file/jpeg from being decoded by applying a password. I'd guess that is what the 'secret.txt' contains? If not then you can run another tool called stegbreak, which uses a wordlist in an attempt to break the password via brute force.